# Multi-threaded web requests in python -- 'Name or service not known'

Tags: python, multithreading, dns, urllib2, multiprocessing

I have a large scraping job to do -- most of the script's time is spent blocking due to a lot of network latency. I'm trying to multi-thread the script so I can make multiple requests simultaneously, but about 10% of my  threads die with the following error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

The other 90% complete successfully. I am requesting multiple pages from the same domain, so it seems like there may be some DNS issue. I make 25 requests at a time (25 threads). Everything works fine if i limit myself to 5 requests at a time, but once I get to around 10 requests, I start seeing this error sometimes.

I have read [Repeated host lookups failing in urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555026/repeated-host-lookups-failing-in-urllib2)
which describes the same issue I have and followed the suggestions therein, but to no avail.

I have also tried using the multiprocessing module instead of multi-threading, I get the same behaviour -- about 10% of the processes die with the same error -- which leads me to believe this is not an issue with urllib2 but something else.

Can someone explain what is going on and suggest how to fix?

**UPDATE**

If I manually code the ip address of the site into my script everything works perfectly, so this error happens sometime during the DNS lookup.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? You may be running into some anti-denial-of-service stuff, or if the server isn't that heavy-weight, then you may actually be overloading it...

Comment: It is a major website that is capable of handling hundreds or thousands of simultaneous requests, my 25 doesn't even make a tiny dent. I'm pretty sure it's a dns resolution issue, because if I replace the domain name with the ip address my script runs perfectly -- so the website isn't explicitly shutting me out. At this point I just want to understand why the DNS lookups are failing.

Comment: Then it may be an issue with the DNS server only allowing so many requests from a client over a certain amount of time, or what have you.

Comment: I've never used this, so I'm not recommending it per se, but something like this would probably solve your problem: http://freshmeat.net/projects/pydnscache/

Comment: I have the same problem right now with a scrapper I am coding. Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: Try enabling a DNS cache in your system, such as [nscd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/nscd.8.html). This should eliminate DNS lookup problems if your scraper always makes requests to the same domain.

Make sure that the file objects returned by `urllib2.urlopen` are properly closed after being read, in order to free resources. Otherwise, you may reach the limit of max open sockets in your system.

Also, take into account the [politeness policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Politeness_policy) web crawlers should have to avoid overloading a server with multiple requests.

Comment: I have done both of these things, the other stack overflow question I linked to in my post makes both of these suggestions, but it doesn't solve my problem. Using the IP address directly rather than the domain does, but I don't understand why nscd doesn't solve this problem, since it seems to be related to DNS caching.